# Calculating (summarizing) atribute values of each point included in certain polygons using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

in ArcMap 10.0 I have one point shapefile (some address layer with number of citizens) and one polygon shapefile (geomorphological segmentation). I need to add up citizens who live in certain area.

I can do select by location of course, but how can I automatically count all citizens from attribute in selected features (point) and add it to the polygon shapefile attribute to each polygon, without manually summarizing fields from selected feature (there are plenty of polygons)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you could do a spatial join:
Join the polygon features to the point features. This should give each point information about which polygon it intersects with. Then you can use summarize with the field containing the info about the polygon and use "Sum" for statistics on the population field. Then you can join the resulting table from the summarize tool back to the polygons.